# Switch between bootstrap tabs

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am a complete beginner at html and I'm trying to follow along with bootstrap but it appears there is something fundamental that I am overlooking. My code will make the tabs but I cannot get it to switch between the two tabs.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Welcome to website</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#home" class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#profile" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Data</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home">
          <p>this is the home tab</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="data">
          <p>this is the data tab</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be just a naming issue.

```
<a href="#profile" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Data</a>
```

should be

```
<a href="#data" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Data</a>
```

since the second tab's id is "data", not "profile".

Comment: I probably rewrote parts of this code 3 times and never caught this